# ViewPager in AlertDialog showing both fragments instead of one at a time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to display a ViewPager with multiple fragments inside an AlertDialog. The ViewPager is set up with a custom FragmentStateAdapter, and I have defined two fragments: ChatGanerelFragment and ChatMembersFragment. However, when I show the AlertDialog, both fragments are being displayed simultaneously instead of one at a time as expected.

I have checked the layout file for the AlertDialog and ensured that the ViewPager and TabLayout are properly defined and not overlapping. I have also reviewed the XML layout files and the code within the fragments for any errors or conflicts, but everything seems fine.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the implementation of the AlertDialog or the interactions with the fragments. Could you please help me identify what might be causing both fragments to be shown together instead of switching between them?

I have included the relevant code snippets below for reference:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this);
View dialogView1 = LayoutInflater.from(ChatActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.chat_manage_team, null);
builder.setView(dialogView1);
TabLayout tabLayout = dialogView1.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
ViewPager2 viewPager = dialogView1.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ChatPagerAdapter adapter = new ChatPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab, position) -> {
     tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
}).attach();
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

and this is the adapter

```java
// Code for the ChatPagerAdapter
public class ChatPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public ChatPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ChatGanerelFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ChatMembersFragment();
            default:
                return  new ChatGanerelFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

this is the layout

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_pager"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

YO!
I found a solution , you would have to change the dialog's xml file instead of using a Constraint Layout use a Linear Layout and give the viewpager as height 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```